# dynamic ng-module variable angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I took an example from angularjs.org start page and added some features. One can add new items to the list and they can be nested. But there`re now more than one submit-form and they still share the same ng-module. I need a dynamically generated ng-module variable which exactly is not a big problem as far as I understand. But I have one on functional side where I need to use value assigned to ng-module. If I make a dynamically generated ng-module variable how can I use it then inside the function in the code below (I mean the todoList.todoText in todoList.addTodo):

```js
angular.module('todoApp', [])
  .controller('TodoListController', function() {
    var todoList = this;
    todoList.todos = [
      {text:'learn angular', done:true},
      {text:'build an angular app', done:false, 
        todos:[
          {text:'plan', done: false},
          {text:'code', done: false}
        ]
      }
    ];
 
    todoList.addTodo = function(todo) {  
      if (!todo) {
        todoList.todos.push({text:todoList.todoText, done:false});
        return;
      }
      if (!todo.todos) {
        todo.todos = [];
      }
      todo.todos.push({text:todoList.todoText, done:false});
      todoList.todoText = '';
    };
 
    todoList.archive = function() {
      var oldTodos = todoList.todos;
      todoList.todos = [];
      angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
        if (!todo.done) todoList.todos.push(todo);
      });
    };
  });
```

```html
<h2>Todo</h2>
    <div ng-controller="TodoListController as todoList">
      [ <a href="" ng-click="todoList.archive()">archive</a> ]
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
            <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
        </label>
        <form ng-submit="todoList.addTodo(todo)">
          <input type="text" ng-model="todoList.todoText"  size="30"
                 placeholder="add new todo here">
          <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
        </form> 
        <ul ng-if="todo.todos">
          <li ng-repeat="todo in todo.todos" ng-include="'categoryTree'">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
              <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
            </label>
            <form ng-submit="todoList.addTodo(todo)">
              <input type="text" ng-model="todoList.todoText"  size="30"
                     placeholder="add new todo here">
              <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
            </form> 
          </li>
        </ul>
      </script>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos" ng-include="'categoryTree'"></li>
      </ul>
      <form ng-submit="todoList.addTodo()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoList.todoText"  size="30"
               placeholder="add new todo here">
        <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
      </form> 
    </div>
```

I know how to solve the problem by means of JavaScript/JQuery but I want to understand how that could be done with Angularjs

Comment: I think you don't get a response because your explanation doesn't make sense. ng-module variables don't exist. Angular uses modules. It's a way to devide code in modules/namespaces/packages. Personally, I wouldn't use multiple.

Comment: Based on your code I suspect these are some possible solutions. From easy to hard: 1. Add a property to every todo like `newChildToDo` 2. Add a property on every  child scope of ng-repeat using ng-init 3. Create a second controller TodoItemController for every todo using ng-controller and pass it a todo using ng-init. 4. Create a directive for a todo list. 5. create a ng-recurse directive. (I haven't tested it)